# Ckeditor post html content by ajax form submit method

Tags: php, ajax, forms, ckeditor

I have a simple form textarea with ckeditor that is...

```
<textarea class="form-control ckeditor" name="ex" id="ex">My Description</textarea>
 and this the content getting by alert.
<p>My description</p>
```

Now I am submitting the form by malsup ajax form submit method to backend file. But I am not getting this value in `$_POST['ex'];`

`var_dump($_POST['ex'])` is giving null string.
I also tried `htmlentities()` but it is not working. How can I insert this description to `mysql` database. Because  it is not a string. I need this description on backend file.

Can someone provide me example for this flow.

Comment: The textarea content is blank, Won't the content be inside <textarea></textarea>?

Comment: @MaK, <textarea></textarea> is a ckeditor that is generate html content. and It should come in php variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor creates a iframe that replaces the textarea, the actual textarea is not used. What you might need to do is update the textarea before submitting.

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances)
{
    CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
}
```

Then at server side  ,just do your things

```
echo $_POST['ex'];
```

Comment: thanks, please tell me what will be instanceName here.

Comment: it is just a variable set by loop for each instances in CKEDITOR

Comment: Thanks for the reply.